# What does this mean from GoF book?

Tags: design-patterns

From book 'Design Patterns':

> The abstractions that emerge during design are key to making a design
>   flexible.

What exactly 'abstractions' here mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An **abstraction** is a generalization of a concept, where unneeded details are removed (i.e. abstracted) in order to better describe some facet of a specific concept. For example, an abstraction of a car could be a vehicle that has four tires, an engine, can hold five passengers, etc. The details, such as the material that the seats are made of and the molecular bonds that are broken during combustion in the engine are superfluous in this case (they only muddle the concept we are trying to describe).

In the case of software, we constantly work with abstractions because they allow us to take complex concepts and distill them down into manageable units. For example, we can say that a student has the following **attributes**:

1. name
2. ID
3. grade

In this case, we do not care about the past of the student (who her parents were, what town she grew up in, etc.) and other extra details. In the case of our system, we only care that the student has a student ID, a name, and is enrolled in a specific grade.

Furthermore, in the case of patterns, we abstract classes and groups of classes into more manageable units. For example, if we can have a class that represents a store data (code written in Java):

```
public class Data { /* ... */ }

public class MySqlDataStore {

    public void store(Data data) {
        // ... write the data to a MySQL database ...
    }
}
```

This suffices for most cases, but what if we want to have multiple ways of storing data? I.e. what if we do not want to marry our system to MySQL? To solve this, we can abstract our MySQL data store into an interface:

```
public interface DataStore {
    public void store(Data data);
}

public class MySqlDataStore implements DataStore {

    @Override
    public void store(Data data) {
        // ... write the data to a MySQL database ...
    }
}
```

Now the rest of the system can depend on the `DataStore` interface rather than the `MySqlDataStore`. This means that our system now only knows about the abstraction of a data store (that it can store data) rather than the specifics of *how* a specific store stores data.

Comment: Missing 'implements DataStore'

Comment: ....and we can then have multiple specific implementations of an abstraction, thus providing flxibility to system as we can have wide range of implementations to choose from...right?

Comment: (@sfiss Thank you) @Mandroid: Yes, but this is only one of the benefits of abstraction. In large systems, we can abstract entire portions of a system into a Facade (see Facade Pattern) or abstract the logic for performing certain actions (see Strategy Pattern). As you read through GoF, you will get a much deeper and more intiutive understanding of abstraction: All of the patterns (and the coolness and cleverness of them) rest on abstraction.